# Order UITableView by distance in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, distance

I'm making a application that needs to display a table with a list of stores sorted on the basis of my position.

Currently I have created a NSMutableArray that contains all objects of type StoreModel.

Objects of type StoreModel are composed of the following fields:

```
class StoreModel: NSObject {

var idStore : Int = Int();
var storeName : String = String();
var latitude: Double = 0;
var longitude: Double = 0;
```

}

I'd like to then display a table that is populated based on the distance from my position.

How can I do ?

Comment: @Eric D. Thank you for correcting my question. Sorry for my English

Comment: You should try to resolve this issue on backend query and not in frontend

Comment: You're welcome - but your English is ok, these were just a few cosmetic corrections. :)

Comment: @Mazel Tov Why backend?

Comment: I suppose you want to list all stores in 10km range of the user, i also suppose you got those stores in some database so you need to figure out just the query... With parse.com it is very easy, i also saw how to do it in pho so u can juat google that

Comment: @MazelTov - Is not possible to do the sorting in the backend because the information on the stores are loaded from a local database SQLIte, which is updated every fifteen days.